# Recomendation for Webshop with API

Tags: mysql, linux, api, shopping

I'm searching for a webshop. The problem with my search is, that the webshop-software of my choice needs to have a useabel API or some interface for external applications. E.g. i need to place orders by an external application or need to get product descriptions or warehouse stock from the external application. I somehow would like to have a webshop wehere the webinterface is just one way to interact with the whole system.

There are some other requirments, which have to be fullfilled, but i guess they are kind of common:

- running on linux
- MySQL (we already have MySQL-replication and backup in place)
- i like open source but i'm willing to pay for it, if it's worth it

I found some webshops on the net - but perhaps you can tell me, if theres any hope for a webshop with a good API before i go and test all of them, on the first look i didn't find any docs about any interface to external applications for any of my search results.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is fast becoming the favoured open source e-commerce platform. (eBay recently acquired it, but don't let that put you off.) All versions, including the free Community Edition are still licensed under [OSL-3.0](http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php) and they also offer a paid Enterprise Edition (compare editions [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/compare)) as well as a [hosted version.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/go/)

The Magento API is documented [here,](http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api) and the [create your own API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api) feature allows you to build a custom API to expose as a webservice to third-parties. System requirements (Linux, PHP, MySQL, Apache) are detailed [here.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements)

Comment: There are also lots of Magento questions and answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento

Comment: Looks promising! Thank you a lot ...
I hope i get the time to look into it the next few days.